# How can I backup Google Drive into AWS Glacier?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-glacier

I want to backup whatever new file or folder added to my Google Drive into AWS Glacier through a linux instance running in an EC2 instance.
I have gone through some AWS Glacier clients, but they are for uploading files from and downloading to local system.

https://www.cloudwards.net/best-backup-tools-amazon-glacier/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rclone may able to help you. Rclone is a command line program to sync files and directories to and from

Google Drive

Amazon S3

Openstack Swift / Rackspace cloud files / Memset Memstore

Dropbox

Google Cloud Storage

Amazon Drive

Microsoft OneDrive

Hubic

Backblaze B2

Yandex Disk

SFTP

The local filesystem

https://github.com/ncw/rclone

Comment: I'm able to backup the Google Drive to Amazon S3 not Glacier, and there I'm changing the storage class of the object (files in S3) to GLACIER storage class(with the help of Lifecycle Rule).

Answer (score 3):

Writing the steps (may be helpful to someone)

We need to create remotes for Google Drive and Amazon S3

I'm using Ubuntu server on AWS EC2 instance.

1. Download appropriate file from https://rclone.org/downloads/ - Linux ARM - 64 Bit (in my case)
2. Copy the downloaded file from local to server (using scp command) and extract the file. OR extract the file on local itself and copy the extracted files to the server (because I was facing problem in extracting it on server)
3. ssh into the ubuntu server.
4. Go inside the folder - rclone-v1.36-linux-amd64 (in my case)
5. Execute the following commands:

   Copy binary file

   `$ sudo cp rclone /usr/bin/
   $ sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/rclone
   $ sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/rclone`

   Install manpage

   `$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man1
   $ sudo cp rclone.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/
   $ sudo mandb`

   Run rclone config to setup. See rclone config docs for more details.

   `$ rclone config`
6. After executing rcolne config command, choose the number/alphabet of option you want to select. Once reached to Use auto config? part, enter N (as we are working on remote server)
7. Paste the link you got in local browser, copy the verification code and enter the the code in the terminal.
8. Confirm, by entering y
9. Enter n to create another remote for Amazon S3, and repeat the same procedure.

   Use the following links for various rclone commands and options:

   https://rclone.org/docs/

   https://linoxide.com/file-system/configure-rclone-linux-sync-cloud/